# One answer useful but solution found by myself

Tags: discussion

I ask a question, and then I receive an answer useful but that "open my mind" to find a solution

Is it the right behaviour accept the answer and editing the own question with the solution or write the solution in a new own answer and then accept it after 2 days?

Comment: Depends on how close the useful answer was. If not too close, post your own (but upvoting the helpful answer is probably right). If very close, suggest the answerer to edit the last bit in.

Comment: @DanielFischer And that answers the question (if only it were an answer).

Comment: @AshRj Since nobody else did answer in the meantime, it has now become one.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160303/how-should-i-accept-a-half-answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way depends on how close the answer was to completely solving your problem.

If it was very close, and you only needed to add a small step, suggest to the answerer that (s)he edits the last step in. If that is done, accept it. If the answerer doesn't react, if it is a small enough finishing touch, you can edit it into the answer yourself - but suggested edits tend to be rejected when they are substantially changing a post, so that route is only for really small finishing touches.

If the answer was sufficiently far away from completely solving the problem, but took you a long part of the way to the solution, answer yourself, giving proper credit to the first answer (upvoting it would be appropriate since it was helpful), and accept yours.

Where the line between almost complete and "sufficiently incomplete" is, must be decided by you, on a case-by-case basis, there is not one rule that fits all.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself: *is the proffered answer the same one that you used? Did it answer all of your question, or only part of it?*

If it isn't/didn't then don't mark it as accepted. Of course you can still up vote it and leave an appropriate comment if you feel the need.

If you can correctly answer your own question and your answer is sufficiently different from the previous answer then do post it and mark it answer in 2 days time.